# OpenGL glBufferData

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-c++, glut, glew

I am using the following tutorial as a guide to make [a model loader](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/) and I have come across a problem. When I use

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Point3D), &vertices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glFlush();
```

I get the following problems:

- Error: identifier `glBufferData` is undefined
- Error: identifier `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` is undefined
- Error: identifier `GL_STATIC_DRAW` is undefined

I have included the libraries into the linker so that should not be the problem. I am including glut.h, Windows.h and gl.h so that shouldn't be the problem either.

I have now added the glew library in both the linker input properties and the source code but I am getting a completely new error now (runtime). I took a screenshot of it:

[image: screenshot of error text]

Comment: The standard Windows OpenGL headers only contain functions up to OpenGL 1.1. Functions from newer versions need to be loaded dynamically. Many people use extension loading libraries (like e.g. GLEW) to handle this.

Comment: You don't just link to glew. You need to make glew actually load the gl functions. Better look at an introduction to glew.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Can you prompt me? I have the same problem like Kinggadino has. I've got glew library and have included it in my program ```#include "glew.h"
#include <glut.h>```, but the program doesn't compile: _Error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "__imp____glewBufferData"_. What am  I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Mike_Device I have never used GLEW. But chances are that you either missed to link against the GLEW library, or link against an incompatible version (e.g. 32-bit vs. 64-bit).

Answer (score -1):

I find this question is quiet simple to be solved.
You can visit [Glad](https://glad.dav1d.de/) and generate the API with the target version of gl you looking for. Unzip the file and include the path to /glad/include in your IDE, and, the error gone!

Note: If you `#include <glad/glad.h>` and `<GLFW/glfw3.h>` in the same time, remember to add a preprocessor : `#define GLFW_INCLUDE_NONE` in front of them. *Ref : [glfw tutorial](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/build_guide.html)*